# How do I manage having multiple screens with different sets of controls in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm creating the game of strategic tic-tac-toe in C# using WinForms. I have the main game screen all contained inside a `TableLayoutPanel`, and as of right now I have the app close when somebody wins.

[Current state of the board, if helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmOcc.png)

I want to create a separate screen within the same form that displays a congratulating message to the winner, but my current idea (using a `panel` to hold the win screen, and programmatically toggling its visibility) feels clunky to design. How should I manage these multiple sets of controls efficiently and comfortably?

Comment: You could add a new Form that displays the win screen.  Then show this form after they win.

Comment: This would create a new window, right? I'd prefer to keep everything inside of one window, if possible.

Comment: What kind of UI development are you familiar with? For example, if you're used to HTML, the Panel can be thought of as a div element, and just like in web development, showing and hiding divs is very common. I'm curious why showing and hiding the panel feels clunky to you.

Comment: I am new to UI development. By "clunky", I mean that it's hard to work with in Visual Studio's design mode. In the provided screenshot, the 9 blank squares are each inside a panel that also contains a TableLayoutPanel. The TableLayoutPanel is covered by the square, rendering it very hard to go back and change. Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this.  One way would be to create a new `UserControl` for your win screen.  This makes it easy to edit the win screen without having to mess with things on your Form.

Then on your Form, the controls would be laid out like this. Form1 containing a `Panel`. The `Panel` containing a `WinScreenUserControl` and a `TableLayoutPanel` (for the game board).

[image: Control Hierarchy]

You probably want the win screen and the `TableLayoutPanel` docked in the Panel.  Send the `WinScreenUserControl` to the back, so it's behind the `TableLayoutPanel`.  Now the win screen will be out of the way for when you want to edit the game board.  And if you want to edit the win screen you just open the `WinScreenUserControl`.

When the game is won you simply call `winScreenUserControl1.BringToFront();` to bring the win screen in front of the game board.

You could also make the game board a `UserControl` and edit it like the win screen.

Answer (score 0):

Panels can work nicely. If you've ever seen a bit of video game design, you'll often have a 'SceneManager' which is just a object you create yourself for switching UI. which has a sole purpose of displaying the correct piece of UI, which handles exactly what you're describing.

I think your first job is to get your entire game in a panel if you haven't already, should be easy enough.

You then create your own SceneManager class object, which will just have two properties which are panels. You then add a method 'DisplayWinPanel()' which will hide the visibility of the main game panel and show the win panel.

```
class SceneManager
{

    public Panel MainGamePanel { private get; set; }
    public Panel WinPanel { private get; set; }

    public SceneManager(Panel MainGamePanel, Panel WinPanel)
    {
        this.MainGamePanel = MainGamePanel;
        this.WinPanel = WinPanel;
    }

    public void ShowWinPanel()
    {
        MainGamePanel.Hide();
        WinPanel.Show();
    }

}
```

Then in your form logic, you'll have a public global variable which is the scene manager, and you'd initialize it in the form_load() method, and also assign your two panels in there.

```
    private SceneManager sceneManager;

    ...

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sceneManager = new SceneManager(panel1, panel2);

        // When win, display win screen
        sceneManager.ShowWinPanel();
    }
```

Then you can easily reference the scene manager from anywhere inside your logic and hide and display panels.

The point of this is that it makes it easy for you to add more management. For example, say you decided to add a menuPanel, you can then have logic to handle that in your scene manager. You can keep this going further and further, but the point is that the SceneManager makes it easy to do what you're describing, otherwise it gets messy.

My suggestion may not be the best, but it's a good start. Other people do it different ways so there isn't really a wrong way (but there are better ways).